# Why should I use '&' instead of '<' for output bindings?

Tags: angularjs

What is the advantage to using '&' instead of '<' for output bindings? '<' can receive a function from the parent, which can be called by the child, passing an argument from the child's scope to the parent's.

Further, it has a much more sensible syntax: Plain JavaScript instead of AngularJS parsing the argument names and requiring you to pass arguments as elements in an object.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that sometimes you want to pass other argument too, like this for example:

```
<directive ng-repeat="item in items" on-smth="dosmth($a, item)"></directive>
```

Inside directive (& binding):

```
scope.onSmth({ $a: internalVariable })
```

How would you do it with < binding?

```
scope.onSmth(internalVariable)
```

And in template:

```
<directive ng-repeat="item in items" on-smth="dosmth"></directive>
```

You can't pass additional `item` parameter here.

Comment: Why not just use a nested function? Outer function accepts template variables, inner function combines them with controller variables.

Comment: @michaelAdam can you write down what you mean?

Comment: On parent controller: this.dosmth = (templateVar) => { return (childControllerVar) => { dosmthelse...}}